# Why does adding "helper: "clone";" to this ui-draggable element prevent it from being dragged?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, draggable, pseudo-element

All I want is to have a `<ul>` with a box-shadow that appears over it's child `<li>` elements, and for those elements to be sortable within the `<ul>`.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrETm/3/), and here's the code:

HTML:

```
<ul class="shadowed">
    <div class="dragMe"></div>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
.shadowed {
    width: 256px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 100px;
    background: #777;
}

.shadowed:before { 
    content: "";
    width: 256px; 
    height: 64px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 100px;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 2px #000;
}

.dragMe {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background: red;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".dragMe" ).draggable({

        /* try dragging the red square, then remove this line and try again. */
        helper: "clone",


        revert: "invalid",
        stack: ".dragMe"
    });

    $( ".shadowed" ).droppable().sortable().disableSelection();   
});
```

In this example, I have a `<ul>` with a child `<li>` (the red box). The `<ul>` "has" a box-shadow in the form of a pseudo-element to cause the shadow to appear over the child elements.

The red box—before being made draggable via jQuery-UI—appears beneath the shadow as expected. However, upon making this element draggable, it appears above the shadow. Dragging the red box in this state works as expected.

**Why does making the element draggable place it in front of the shadow?**

Additionally, giving the red box a `helper: "clone"` puts it back beneath the shadow, but prevents it from being dragged.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: It may have to do with the absolute position in the .shadowed:before. I removed this and although it changed the formatting, it re-enabled the dragging. Please post solution when solved. I'm curious.

Answer (score 2):

So the box shadow overlay on top of the elements is making the div below unclickable.

I updated the jsfidle example to make this clear by adding another div, and making another mod too

```
 <div class="dragMe"> </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rrETm/4/

A possible way to remedy this is by intercepting the click, hiding the box shadow overlay and then simulating the click, and then re-showing the box shadow, but it seems a bit complicated. Some code to start on this approach is in the linked example below.

[Jquery pass click through element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398787/jquery-pass-click-through-element)

Comment: How's this for a hack?
http://jsfiddle.net/wk8md/
You can drag the boxes now, since there's nothing covering them, but I still need to add some kind of z-index transition on drag so that you can't see the shadows over the red/blue box during dragging.