# Propagate click event to underlaying element

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-propagation

On my website, I display some elements over each other. But all of them have to be click able, even if there's an other element displayed over them.

Unfortunately, the elements are on the same level, not nestled. So I can't simply propagate the click event to the parent element.

I created a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cFzaB/) to describe my problem: When you click on the `overlay` element, the click event should be propagated to `elemenet1` or `element2`, depending on where you have clicked.

Comment: track mouse position in element

Comment: have you checked this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398787/jquery-pass-click-through-element

Comment: Thank a lot! That's exactly what I was searching for! So my question is clearly a duplicate - what should we do? If you want to, you can answer it with the reference to the other question so I can mark this question as solved. Or should I delete it?